# How to add actionbar to an default Google Maps API in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I just created an Google Maps activity by selecting the default Google Maps Activity. However, I found that there is no actionbar on the top.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

My question is how to add an actionbar to it. Do I have to change the extends from FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity? I am very new to Android, please explain using the most basic languages.

Comment: Yes, try to extend from `AppCompatActivity`. Then, as official documentation says: *You can add an ActionBar to your activity [...] setting the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme.*. Check your *AndroidManifest.xml* and *styles.xml* to make sure of that. If you are unsure, post the content of these files.

Comment: @lorenzo-s, but in this case, I will not be able to use Google Map API then.

Answer (score 2):

Just `extend AppCompatActivity` as most of the answers have suggested.

`public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
OnMapReadyCallback {`
}

Tried it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a detailed answer, I would check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html), these docs have two different answers: one for Android 3 and above (what I recommend to do) and another one for support from 2.1.

You have to define properly what is the lowest Android version you want to support, I recommend `Android 4.0 (API 14)`: easy to implement and covers most devices of the market > 90%.

**>3.0**

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar is included in all activities

**>2.1**

The complicated point is that the `ActionBarActivity` (mentioned in the doc) is deprecated so you must use `AppCompatActivity` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)). Therefore you need to include the android **v7-appcompat** library.

Normally, changing from `FragmentActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`should not cause any trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem is more about how to have both Google API together with an actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend your activity from `AppCompatActivity` use this line of code
   in your `.java` class  under set
   **setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);**

   `mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

**And**

2. Use `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` in your
   Fragment in `.xml` class as
   `<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               android:id="@+id/map"
               class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               tools:context="com.pro.soft.inzi.tracky.Live" />`

**Note:** must edit this **fragment's** last line and put you package name and class name instead of `"com.pro.soft.inzi.tracky.Live"`